# Параметры метода Java

Tags: java, android, параметры

Как сделать, чтобы `s1` и `s2` передавались в `setLogView` по отдельности, а там складывались?

```
 public void Rand_1 (int sA) {
    int a = 0; // Начальное значение диапазона - "от"
    int b = 4; // Конечное значение диапазона - "до"
    int A = a + (int) (Math.random() * b); // Генерация 1-го числа
    int B = a + (int) (Math.random() * b); // Генерация 2-го числа
    int C = a + (int) (Math.random() * b); // Генерация 3-го числа
    int D = a + (int) (Math.random() * b); // Генерация 4-го числа
    if (A == sA) {
        String s2 = "Передается эта строчка";
        setLogView(s2);
    }
    if (B == sA) {
      String s2 = "Передается эта строчка";
        setLogView(s2);
    }
    if (C == sA) {
      String s2 = "Передается эта строчка";
        setLogView(s2);
    }
    if (D == sA) {
  String s2 = "Передается эта строчка";
        setLogView(s2);
    }
    } else {
 String s2 = "Передается другая строчка";
        setLogView(s2);
    }
    }
}

public void Rand_2 (int sB) 
//_________________________________________
//Аналогия со вторым,параметр s1
    int a = 0; // Начальное значение диапазона - "от"
    int b = 4; // Конечное значение диапазона - "до"
    int A = a + (int) (Math.random() * b); // Генерация 1-го числа

    int B = a + (int) (Math.random() * b); // Генерация 2-го числа

    int C = a + (int) (Math.random() * b); // Генерация 3-го числа

    int D = a + (int) (Math.random() * b); // Генерация 4-го числа

    if (A == sB) {
        String s1 = "s1 передается";
        setLogView(s1);

//______________________________________________
// вот "Это" принимает входные параметры
public void setLogView(String s1,String s2) {
    TextView LogView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LogView);
    LogView.setText(s1 + (String.valueOf(Dam)) + s2 + (String.valueOf(DamHe)));
```

Comment: А в чем проблема? Где ошибки, логи или что-то еще, что не устраивает? И почему?

Comment: Не вызывайте метод а прибавляйте текст к глобальной переменной. Последняя добавка уже должна вызвать метод

Comment: Вернуться на предыдущий уровень в деле усвоения грамоты.

Comment: Отредактировал отступы в коде и перестал понимать, как соотносятся открывающие и закрывающие скобки. Проверьте их, пожалуйста.

Comment: @flippy Попробую,спасибо)

Comment: Ещё у `TextView` есть метод `append`, который добавляет текст к существующему - тоже можно применить.

Answer (score 0):

Вынеси эти переменные в поля класса и на конечном этапе вызывай нужный метод.

Comment: Постарайтесь дать более развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов решить вашу задачу несколько. Что-то похожее на "передать по отдельности" можно реализовать так: измените ваши методы `Rand_1` и `Rand_2` чтобы они возвращали результат своих вычислений, а затем в нужном месте вызывайте `setLogView`, передавая туда этот результат:

```
public String Rand_1 (int sA) {
    int a = 0; // Начальное значение диапазона - "от"
    int b = 4; // Конечное значение диапазона - "до"
    int A = a + (int) (Math.random() * b); // Генерация 1-го числа
    int B = a + (int) (Math.random() * b); // Генерация 2-го числа
    int C = a + (int) (Math.random() * b); // Генерация 3-го числа
    int D = a + (int) (Math.random() * b); // Генерация 4-го числа
    if (A == sA) {
        return "Передается эта строчка";
    }
    if (B == sA) {
        return "Передается эта строчка";
    }
    if (C == sA) {
        return "Передается эта строчка";
    }
    if (D == sA) {
        return "Передается эта строчка";
    }

    return "Передается другая строчка";
}

public String Rand_2 (int sB) 
//_________________________________________
//Аналогия со вторым,параметр s1
    int a = 0; // Начальное значение диапазона - "от"
    int b = 4; // Конечное значение диапазона - "до"
    int A = a + (int) (Math.random() * b); // Генерация 1-го числа

    int B = a + (int) (Math.random() * b); // Генерация 2-го числа

    int C = a + (int) (Math.random() * b); // Генерация 3-го числа

    int D = a + (int) (Math.random() * b); // Генерация 4-го числа

    if (A == sB) {
        return "s1 передается";
    } else {
        return "что-то другое";
}
```

И там, где нужно:

```
setLogView(Rand_1(sA), Rand_2(sB));
```